# Mongodb get error message "MongoError: Path collision at activity"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose library for the mongodb on my node.js project. On of my logs file getting the mongodb error message:

```
{
  message: 'Path collision at activity',
  stack: 'MongoError: Path collision at activity\n' +
    '    at Connection.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:61)\n' +
    '    at Connection.emit (events.js:315:20)\n' +
    '    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n' +
    '    at processMessage (/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:364:10)\n' +
    '    at Socket.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:533:15)\n' +
    '    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)\n' +
    '    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)\n' +
    '    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)\n' +
    '    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)\n' +
    '    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)\n' +
    '    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)',
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1600849377 },
  ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'Path collision at activity',
  code: 31250,
  codeName: 'Location31250',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 2, high_: 1600849377 },
    signature: {
      hash: Binary {
        _bsontype: 'Binary',
        sub_type: 0,
        position: 20,
        buffer: <Buffer d2 34 b7 ac bc a7 3f ea 38 d1 5c e3 26 58 39 43 d8 11 6c 83>
      },
      keyId: Long { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 4, high_: 1596659428 }
    }
  },
  name: 'MongoError',
  level: 'info',
  timestamp: '2020-09-23 08:22:57',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

This error did not point the location of error that on which function return this error.
If anyone have anyclue then kindly let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the query being sent?

Comment: actually this is because of the wrong query you wrote

Answer (score 30):

The problem should rely in the projection. This error is introduced as part of breaking change since v4.4.

From [MongoDB 4.4 release notes here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.4-compatibility/#path-collision-restrictions):

> #### Path Collision: Embedded Documents and Its Fields
>
> Starting in MongoDB 4.4, it is illegal to project an embedded document with any of the embedded document’s fields.
>
> For example, consider a collection inventory with documents that contain a size field:
>
> ```
> { ..., size: { h: 10, w: 15.25, uom: "cm" }, ... }
> ```
>
> Starting in MongoDB 4.4, the following operation fails with a Path collision error because it attempts to project both size document and the size.uom field:
>
> ```
> db.inventory.find( {}, { size: 1, "size.uom": 1 } )  // Invalid starting in 4.4
> ```
>
> In previous versions, lattermost projection between the embedded documents and its fields determines the projection:
>
> - If the projection of the embedded document comes after any and all projections of its fields, MongoDB projects the embedded document. For example, the projection document `{ "size.uom": 1, size: 1 }` produces the same result as the projection document `{ size: 1 }`.
> - If the projection of the embedded document comes before the projection any of its fields, MongoDB projects the specified field or fields. For example, the projection document `{ "size.uom": 1, size: 1, "size.h": 1 }` produces the same result as the projection document `{ "size.uom": 1, "size.h": 1 }`

Comment: what to do in this situation?

Comment: @AzamatAbdullaev You should add the 'select' property for nested fields to the `populate()` portion of the query.

Comment: you could also use the unwind aggregation

Answer (score 4):

For the record, I got this error when I wanted to select a set of fields of a populated collection, also paginating them. With this as an *author-book* example:

```
author: {
  _id: ObjectId
  name: String,
  birthday: String,
  ...,
  books: [
    _id: ObjectId,
    _id: ObjectId,
  ]
}

book: {
  _id: ObjectId,
  title: String,
  publisher: String,
  year: string,
  ...
}
```

I was trying to paginate sets of 5 books of the author and select the `title` and `year` fields using:

```
Author.findById(author_id)
  .populate('books')
  .select('books': { $slice: { [offset, limit + offset] } })
  .select('books books.title books.year');
```

Which was throwing the error. Instead, solved it by using `select` property on `populate` function:

```
Author.findById(author_id)
  .populate(
    path: 'books',
    select: 'title year'
  )
  .select('books': { $slice: { [offset, limit + offset] } });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await FFF.findOne({rid: req.body.w.toString()}, {projection:{'c.u':1,'c': {$elemMatch: {k: 12}}}  })
```

Just remove duplicated values like (show c [show everthing from c array], show c.u [show u in c])

```
await FFF.findOne({rid: req.body.w.toString()}, {projection:{'c': {$elemMatch: {k: 12}}}  })
```

Answer (score 0):

*It's because you doing duplicate projection*

**For example :**

```
User.findOne(
    {
        email: "xyz.com"
    },
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        email: 1,
        games: 1,
        mobileNo: 1,
        "games.gameName": 1,
        "games.gameSize": 1
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are composing a complex projection from variables and such, You might need to "clean" the projection (instead of analyzing the flow that built the projection). I wrote a Python method for that:

```
def avoid_projection_path_collision(fields):
    if not fields:
        return None

    fields = list(set(fields))
    fields.sort()
    i = 0
    while True:
        if i+1 == len(fields):
            break
        f = fields[i]
        next_f = fields[i+1]
        if f+"." in next_f:
            fields.remove(next_f)
        else:
            i += 1
    return fields
```

Example: input of ["a.b.c", "a.b"] will output: ["a.b"].

p.s.
If your projection format is {"a":1, "b": 1} you need to pass fields.keys() and rebuild the projection as dict if needed (Pymongo excepts a list and consider it as "include only those field").