# MongoDB unnecessary huge avg document sizes

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, storage

I have a MongoDB-Collection in which I save Commits. Those Commits have an average document size of 3.6 KB.
As I split a few of those Commits to

```
CommitPath {
    commit: Commit;
    path?: GitFile; // this is the representation of a file stored in the commit
}
```

the avg-document-size gets to about 53.9 KB or with further Commits even to about 300 KB.
For each File in a Commit, a CommitPath-Object is created. The Avg-Document-Size of a CommitPath should be more or less the same as the size of a Commit but definitely less or equal than 2*sizeof(Commit) as the only thing stored more in the CommitPath is already stored in the Commit.

I calculate the CommitPaths with a TypeScript-Application compiled to JavaScript and ran with nodejs. As I run the nodejs-Application the CommitPaths total size in RAM-Memory is not even nearly as high as stored in MongoDB which seems very suspicious. I am not using Mongoose and directly saving the Object with MongoClient (npm-package).

I would like to upload the 2 collections but I get a "Path collision at path.changes remaining portion changes"-Error trying to export the CommitPath-Collection.
I have read [Mongodb get error message "MongoError: Path collision at activity"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64059795/mongodb-get-error-message-mongoerror-path-collision-at-activity) but I still don´t understand what exactly causes the problem.

**Can anyone explain why MongoDB makes such large document sizes, why I get this error while exporting the collection and how I can fix that?**

Comment: Your question has multiple questions in it.

Comment: You should be able to use the mongo shell, compass, robo3t, etc. to view the documents in the database, to see why they are large.  The export problem should probably be a separate question, but we would need more details to help with that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzing documents has helped with the problem. I have analyzed the collection with TypeScript like that:

```
import * as bson from "bson" // npm i -D bson && npm i -D @types/bson
const client: MongoClient   = await MongoClient.connect(this.dbConfig.url, {useUnifiedTopology: true});
const db                    = client.db(this.dbConfig.dbName);
const collection            = db.collection(collectionName);
const dbContent             = await collection.find({}).toArray();

dbContent.forEach(doc => {
    const size = bson.calculateObjectSize(x);
    if (size > 100000) {
        console.log(doc)
    }
}
```

The problem was that Commits which affected a lot of files are larger than normal Commits (Commit.files is bigger) and as for each file in those commits the Commit will be stored fully in a CommitPath-object the average document size got much larger than the average document size in the Commit-database.

I still do not know why MongoDBCompass is not able to export collection, but it seems not to be associated with the large average document size.