# Mongodb / mongoose populate not working in mongo version 4.4

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

the code below used to work fine so far, but since updating to mongo 4.4, there are some braking changes.
author has name and other fields.
item has title, price, (more fields), and 'author' which is the id of an author record.
the .populate used to fetch data from the "foreign" record and to be sort of join.
now its producing error: ***MongoError: Path collision at author***.
Any idea?

```
Item.find({ tags: tag })
      .populate({ path: 'author', select: 'name' })
      .sort({ updated: -1 })
      .limit(count)
      .select('_id title author.name price picture')
      .exec(function (err, items) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }

        res.json(items);
      });
```

Edit: so the reason is a change in mongodb ver 4.4 . the syntax above was correct until then, and now it isn't. what's the new syntax?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514620/4168998 Check this answer.

Comment: thanks @v1shva, i saw that one, but doesn't help. i can't believe population is not supported any more. plus, the mongoose documentation does not say a word about that breaking change.  my question is of course: ok, mongodb has changed the rules :( how do i fix that?

Comment: Can you try again without the `.select('_id title author.name price picture')` in query? Also post sample item and author docs here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got it. The $%8*# have changed the rules. So there are some changes in mongodb 4.4, and mongoose is not aware of them. Here is the correct code that works, in case it helps someone in the future:

```
Item.find({ tags: tag })
      .populate('author'})
      .sort({ updated: -1 })
      .limit(count)
      .select('_id title name price picture')  // name here, is author's name.
      .exec(function (err, items) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }

        res.json(items);
      });
```

Note: it's illegal now to have the same field name in the 'main' document and the embedded one. like in this case, if the Item has name, and author has name - this will not work, you would have to change one of the field names.